# Why does apple use NSOrderedSet instead of NSArray for ordered mutli value relationship in CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

In core data if we have multi value relationship, such as when a business can have several keywords,  in the subclass NSManagedObject generator, Apple will use NSOrderedSet instead of NSArray.

They are both almost equal except that checking ownership is slightly faster in NSOrderedSet.

Any reason why Apple doesn't use the far more familiar and famous NSArray?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

My guess would be: Because `NSOrderedSet` manages a collection of *distinct* elements, similar to `NSSet` for unordered relationships.

With `NSArray` you could create an object which is related to another object more than once.

Comment: So given this, why would anyone use NSArray??

Comment: @PostCodeism - Because you might be storing a sequence of non-distinct elements where their position relative to eachother is important. IE, maybe you have an array of letters representing a word or an array of notes representing a song. Letters can repeat in a word and notes can repeat in a song, thus it shouldn't ignore repeated elements, while rearranging them won't give you the same word or song, so it needs to keep track of order, too. If you need order elements that might be repeats, you need an NSArray.

Answer (score 14):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You can use ordered sets as an alternative to arrays when the order of elements is important and performance in testing whether an object is contained in the set is a consideration— testing for membership of an array is slower than testing for membership of a set.

Comment: I've read that docs. The small membership checking seems to be too trivial to be the cause given that most membership has low count. I think Martin's answer is the right one. +1 still.